# Run background thread in QT application

Tags: c++, qt

I want to start a background nonQT thread that will wait for an event. Then process this event in the MainClass QT thread. The app is working on embedded Linux. I Have QT and boost libraries. What's the best way to do this?

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    //....

    mainClass = boost::make_shared<MainClass >(); //this is QTthread

    secondClass = boost::make_shared<secondClass>(); //this is non QT object
    ....

    //do some qt app stuff

    ....

    return app.exec();
}

MainClass::run()
{
 //process an event
}
```

So I want to start a background thread in secondClass and then to continue to work in main. When an event occurs in the secondClass, process it MainClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your C++ standard, you can either use C++11 `std::thread` or, barring that, `pthread_create` to create your thread.

In either case, you will require a Qt object that is accessible from this thread (either by capture or as a global (pointer) variable).

Then, in your thread, if an event has occured, you can use [QMetaObject::invokeMethod](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod-8) to send the event information to your main thread.

(Untested) Example (std::thread)

```
MainClass main;

std::thread([&]()
{
    //Wait for Event
    QMetaObject::invokeObject(&main, std::bind(&MainClass::run, &main));
}).detach();
```

Comment: Emitting a Qt signal from a non-Qt thread also works, as long as the connections were not made explicitly `Qt::DirectConnection`

Comment: @Homer512 But if I create std::thread then I need to detach it to continue QT application?

Comment: @Alex your `secondClass` can hold the thread object. Or the `main` function manages its lifetime.

Comment: @Alex, No. std::thread starts immediately after construction finishes in parallel and the qt application continues running in its own thread. What you do need to do however is either `detach` or `join` before terminating your application, otherwise std::terminate will be triggered upon thread destruction.